# Google Cloud Container Registry List images in subdirectory with gcloud command

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, docker-registry

How can I get a list of images in a "subdirectories" in a Google Cloud Container Registry?

I have those images on GCP:

```
gcr.io/project-id/website/api
gcr.io/project-id/website/api-builder
gcr.io/project-id/website/frontend
gcr.io/project-id/website/frontend-builder
```

But when I issue the command...

```
gcloud container images list
```

It only gives me

```
NAME
gcr.io/project-id/website
```

I would like to be able to get all images for a search query like `project-id/website` and get all 4 images above.

If I issue this command:

```
gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/project-id/website
```

I get no results of course.

I searched Google and checked the help pages to no avail.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question. I went back to GCP and saw this in the user interface:

[image]

So it clicked when I saw the "Repositories" title. Images are in repositories and can be nested.

So I tried this command:

```
gcloud container images list --repository gcr.io/project-id/website
```

And got back

```
NAME
gcr.io/project-id/website/api
gcr.io/project-id/website/api-builder
gcr.io/project-id/website/frontend
gcr.io/project-id/website/frontend-builder
```